# DRF - add argument to Model.save(...)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an `Invoice` model and there is a `recalculate` argument in the overridden `Invoice.save()` method.

I want `Invoice` to be recalculated always except when it's created using it's serializer.

Is it possible?

Serializers use `create` so I'm not sure how to do that. (It's a ModelSerializer)

Comment: You can use signals for this.Signals are fired in all save operations.You can configurated it fire  before or after  save operation. You can find more detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mixin to override the `create` method and pass in the `recalculate` argument, without calling `super().create()`, then use it in your serializer: e.g. `InvoiceSerializer(CreateMixin, serlializers.ModelSerializer)`

```
class CreateMixin:
    def create(self, validated_data, recalculate):
        raise_errors_on_nested_writes('create', self, validated_data)

        ModelClass = self.Meta.model

        info = model_meta.get_field_info(ModelClass)
        many_to_many = {}
        for field_name, relation_info in info.relations.items():
            if relation_info.to_many and (field_name in validated_data):
                many_to_many[field_name] = validated_data.pop(field_name)

        try:
            instance = ModelClass(**validated_data)
            '''
            your custom logic with recalculate argument
            '''


        except TypeError:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            msg = (
                    'Got a `TypeError` when calling `%s.%s.create()`. '
                    'This may be because you have a writable field on the '
                    'serializer class that is not a valid argument to '
                    '`%s.%s.create()`. You may need to make the field '
                    'read-only, or override the %s.create() method to handle '
                    'this correctly.\nOriginal exception was:\n %s' %
                    (
                        ModelClass.__name__,
                        ModelClass._default_manager.name,
                        ModelClass.__name__,
                        ModelClass._default_manager.name,
                        self.__class__.__name__,
                        tb
                    )
            )
            raise TypeError(msg)

        # Save many-to-many relationships after the instance is created.
        if many_to_many:
            for field_name, value in many_to_many.items():
                field = getattr(instance, field_name)
                field.set(value)

        return instance
```

Comment: how do you pass the parameter `recalculate` to the **`create(...)`** method?

Comment: if you refer to my solution, you first create a new mixin called `CreateMixin` and a new method `create()` in it. then you can have `InvoiceSerializer` to inherit from both `CreateMixin` and `serlializers.ModelSerializer` (`CreateMixin` first, then `serlializers.ModelSerializer`) . Based on Python MRO, when you call `create()` from  `InvoiceSerializer`, it will search first search `create()` in `CreateMixin` and use it instead of the `create()` in `serlializers.ModelSerializer`.

Comment: Your explanation didn't answer my question 